# Portrait FormSheet Rotation IPad

Tags: ipad, rotation

I am creating an app on a splitview with tab bar controller. my problem is when i am on portrait and hide the masterview, my formsheet dismisses. Is there a way to prevent the rotation if there is a current formsheet shown?

Answer (score 0):

Include this method in your code, you may want to add an additional if when your form sheet is dismissed.  This bit of code will lock your view to landscape.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations.

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

}

Comment: No sir, I wanted my app to work on all orientations. My problem is when i present a formsheet i wanted to stay portrait, else all orientations. the presenting controller of the formsheet is a popover.